# R Caret GBM Error: Something is wrong with RMSE

Tags: r, performance, parameters, r-caret, gbm

I'm trying to run a GBM model via caret package in R on a regression problem. Following is the code:

```
# Code - train_data_x is a df (All numerical variables - no missing value) & 
# train_data_y is a vector of numerical target variable (Regression Problem)

caret::train(
  x = train_data_x,
  y = train_data_y,
  method = "gbm",
  trControl = fitControl,
  tuneLength = 5
)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
      RMSE        Rsquared        MAE     
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :25    NA's   :25    NA's   :25   
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Further, warnings show the following:

```
Warning messages:
1: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

2: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

3: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

4: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

5: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

6: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

7: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

8: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

9: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

10: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

11: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

12: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

13: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

14: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

15: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

16: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

17: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

18: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

19: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

20: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

21: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

22: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

23: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

24: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

25: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep1: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

26: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

27: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

28: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

29: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

30: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

31: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

32: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

33: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

34: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

35: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

36: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

37: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

38: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

39: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

40: model fit failed for Fold3.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

41: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

42: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

43: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

44: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

45: model fit failed for Fold4.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

46: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

47: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

48: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=3, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

49: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=4, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'

50: model fit failed for Fold5.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=5, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error : 'gbm.fit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm'
```

I've tried running library(gbm) as well as library(caret) before re-running this simple code, but I'm not able to get past this error. This is working for XGBoost and other tree models.

Also, how can we tune ntrees parameter of Random Forest model via caret library, since I can see only mtry being used as tuning parameter while setting method = "rf"?

**Can someone please help with the same? Thanks.**

Comment: I see two multiple questions here, can you take out the part on random forest.. sorry I don't think they are related at all

Comment: if it works for other methods, then most likely your gbm package is not installed properly. can you just try to run ```gbm(....)``` on your data and also provide an example of your dataset ```train_data_x``` and ```train_data_y``` ?????